# How to implement subscription model for an on premise application?

Tags: account-security

We are developing a web application that will run on premise in customer's datacenter for security reasons. We want to sell this application with a subscription based model where we charge X dollars per user per year. The problem we are facing is how to implement this feature? Our current plan is as follows:

1. User has to sign-in before they can do anything
2. The sign-in happens against a server we own. This is the only part where any data is sent from customer's datacenter to external internet.
3. At time of sign-in we can definitely validate whether the customer's account is in good standing and send back a signed response.
4. The client parses the response and let's the user use the application or not.

The trouble in all of this is that a customer who has sufficient knowledge of programming can hack the client code (it will be JavaScript after all) and basically delete all the code that is doing the authorization. How can we stop this from happening?

Comment: This isn't a security question but a program design question. And I would suggest not using a client-side programming approach to perform functions that you want to hide from the client ...